# How to call ftp script from main script

Tags: debian, ftp, postgresql, debian-squeeze, shell-scripting

I'm lookign for a way to create backups from several databases and send result files to server in Debian Linux 6 (Sqeeze) from crontab job
There are databases named database1 .. database4 
Backup from every db shoudl created and sent using ftp

I tried script below, but send.sh script does not finis automatically: it must terminated by keyboard. How to fix ?
How to make script shorter?

Crontab script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PGUSER=postgres
PGPASSWORD=mymass
export PGUSER PGPASSWORD
backupdir=/root/mybackups
backupdate=$(date +%u)

baas=database1
export baas backupdate
fail=${backupdir}/${baas}${backupdate}.backup
pg_dump -U postgres ${baas} -f ${fail}
./saada.sh

baas=database2
export baas backupdate
fail=${backupdir}/${baas}${backupdate}.backup
pg_dump -U postgres ${baas} -f ${fail}
./saada.sh

baas=database3
export baas backupdate
fail=${backupdir}/${baas}${backupdate}.backup
pg_dump -U postgres ${baas} -f ${fail}
./saada.sh

baas=database4
export baas backupdate
fail=${backupdir}/${baas}${backupdate}.backup
pg_dump -U postgres ${baas} -f ${fail}
./saada.sh
```

sending which does not exit saada.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ftp -inp <<EOF
open mybackupsite.com
user backupuser  pass
bin
lcd /root/eeva-backups
delete "${baas}*.backup"
put "${baas}${backupdate}.backup"
bye

#reset PGUSER and PGPASSWORD
#PGUSER=""
#PGPASSWORD=""
#export PGUSER PGPASSWORD
#End

#exit 0
EOF
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `EOF` immediately after `bye`?

Answer (score 0):

[Andrew's comment is probably on the spot](https://serverfault.com/users/188579/andrew-domaszek) however, I discourage anyone from using FTP as transfer method because it sends user/pass without being encrypted first

Is there any compelling reason for not using ssh + rsync?
You would achieve the same result with password-less authentication which is [easily achievable](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password)

Your script would be safer and shorter too

```
rsync --delete -av ${baas}${backupdate}.backup user@server.domain.com:/root/eeva-backups
```